Why would the Day of Christ be equivalent to the Day of the Lord?
Why, as someone said here concerning II Thess 2, would the Day of the Christ be equivalent to the Day of the Lord? Knowing that the Day of the Lord in the OT was a day of judgment on the wicked--and not something believers would look forward to and "rejoice in" as one of the two verses below states.
The following verses, and others in the NT, do not seem at all to align the concept of the Day of Christ with the Day of the Lord (judgment), but rather seem to speak of the Rapture resurrection of believers. And the "gathering together to Him," that begins this very passage, seems to be Paul's main topic. The Thessalonians were afraid they missed the resurrection, a positive event, not judgment on the wicked.

Phil 1:10 "that you may approve the things that are excellent, that
you may be sincere and without offense till the day of Christ,"
Phil 2:16 "holding fast the word of life, so that I may rejoice in the
day of Christ that I have not run in vain or labored in vain."


Why could the resurrection and judgement on the wicked not be the same event as the NT says?

Judgement in the NT is not just a simple event - it pervades the entire Bible.
In “The New Unger's Bible Dictionary”, we have a list a several judgements.  According to Unger, an inductive study of the Scriptures shows that there's more than one general judgement (with which I broadly agree) and goes as far as to specify eight distinct judgements described in the Bible

Judgement of the Cross - This is the judgement upon sin effected by Christ when He said "It is finished" (John 19:30).  It is the basis of the believer’s salvation when he believes. Christ has borne the sinner’s guilt and in Him, as a substitute for all on behalf of whom He died, sin has been judged. The one who believes on Christ has been released from judgment, and “there is therefore now no condemnation” (John 5:24; Rom. 8:1; Gal. 3:13; Heb. 9:26– 28; 1 Pet. 2:24).
Judgement of Believers - This takes the form of divine correction and chastisement (1 Cor. 11:30-32; Heb 12:3-13; John 15:1-9).  The apostle Paul says: “But if we judged ourselves rightly, we should not be judged. But when we are judged, we are disciplined by the Lord in order that we may not be condemned along with the world” (1 Cor. 11:31–32). This, then, involves God’s disciplinary action against a sinning saint. “The sin leading to death” (1 John 5:16; cf. 1 Cor. 5:1–5; Acts 5:1–11) occurs when the believer, through deliberate continued sin, brings reproach upon the name of Christ and upon his salvation by free grace, and forfeits his physical life “that his spirit may be saved in the day of the Lord Jesus.”
Believer's Works - This judgement concerns only Christians and it is not a matter of judgement for sins that have been judged at the cross and with which the believer will not again be faced (John 5:24; Rom. 8:1); it involves instead the divine appraisal of the Christian’s works and service. This will entail reward or loss of reward (2 Cor. 5:10; Rom. 14:10, 12; Eph. 6:8; 2 Tim. 4:8).
Judgement of Self - This is referred to in 1 Cor. 11:31-32.  It has reference to stern criticism of a Christian of his own ways with accommodation to the divine will and immediate confession of and turning away from all sin (1 John 1:7–9). True confession is equivalent to self-judgment and involves immediate cleansing and restoration to fellowship and walking “in the light.”
Judgement of the Nations - This judgement is referred to in Matt. 25:31-46.  It involves divine dealing with the nations on the basis of their treatment of [figurative] Israel. The “goat” nations on the left hand involve those peoples who are sent to the lake of fire. The “sheep” nations on the right hand enter the millennial kingdom. The peculiar basis of this judgment is the way all nations have dealt with Israel during the Tribulation period preceding the second advent of Christ. OT prophecy is clear in its prediction that some Gentile nations will enter the coming kingdom of Israel (cf. Isa. 60:3; 61:6; 62:2). These nations will be subordinate to Israel. As the millennial state merges into the eternal state, Gentile nations are still asserted to be on the earth when the heavenly Jerusalem descends from heaven (Rev. 21:24, 26).
Judgement of Israel - Ezekiel 20:33-44 clearly teaches that Israel must come into judgement before being restored in the millennial kingdom.  This OT teaching has confirmation in the NT from the parable of the ten virgins (Matt. 25:1–13 (see Joel 3:11–15). Prophecy seems to teach that there will be a general resurrection of all truly regenerated Israelites of the past dispensation to be judged. Those who had a kingdom hope are to arise and enter the earthly glory (cf. Ezek. 37:1–14; Dan. 12:1–3).
Judgement of Angels - These are fallen angels and are evidently judged in connection with the great white throne (1 Cor. 6:3; 2 Pet. 2:4; Jude 1:6).
White Throne Judgement - This last great judgement comprehends the judgement of all unsaved of all ages (Rev. 20:11-15).  The basis will be works, which evidently suggests differences and degrees of punishment. All who are not found in “the book of life” are cast into “the lake of fire.” This is called “the second death,” which means final and complete cutting off from God’s presence and a sin-cleansed universe.

To this list, Unger might have added one more:

Judgement of God – this is the doctrine of Theodicy – where everyone is to judge whether God has been just or otherwise and is mentioned several times in places such as Rom 3:4 (“when You are judged”), Rev 14:7 (the judgement of God), Rev 16:4-6 where people declare God to be righteous and just. See also Ezra 9:15, Ps 51:4, 119:33, Neh 9:33, etc.

Thus, the OP question appears to predicated on the questionable assumption that the resurrection and judgement are different events when they are clearly related.
Lastly, the day of Christ" is unique to Philippians and only occurs in 1:6, 10, 2:16.  It is quite natural that "the day of Christ" should be equivalent to "the day of the Lord" (Acts 2:20, 1 Cor 5:5, 2 Cor 1:14, 1 Thess 5:2, 2 Peter 3:10-13) because in the NT "the Lord" is used as a title for Christ as much as "Christ" is.

+1 Excellent answer as usual! The Valley of Jehoshaphat sounds more like a judgment associated with Armageddon, where the returning Jesus and the saints intervene, splitting the Mount of Olives to save Jerusalem. The application of the parable of the 10 virgins is problematic if one goes deeper than peshat, and I'm still working on it. Why 10? The parable reminds me of the wedding of Abigail to David upon the death of Nabal ("foolish"). She also had five bridesmaids who weren't foolish. What do you think of this parallel?

@Dieter - I hope I do not disappoint you if I tell you that the peshat meaning is the one I usually prefer unless another is clearly implied.  In the parable of the 10 virgins, I simply take this illustrate the two classes of Christians (NOT wicked vs righteous) that will exist when Jesus returns; and that these two classes of Christians are distinguished by the amount of oil (= the Holy Spirit) that they have/obey.

Yes, I also give the same priority to the peshat as you do. In addition, I look for allusions to other passages and events. For example, I only recently learned that the palm branches that give Palm Sunday its name was a symbol of the Maccabean Revolt and the Jewish hope for a military-political Messiah to expel the hated Romans, and in parallel to the aspirations that drive Dominion Theology today. So, I don't disagree with the conventional interpretation of this parable, but I suspect that there's more to it than meets the eye--a true remez not to be confused with a drash.

BTW, I don't think the sod exists on this side of sanity.

The day of Christ is equivalent to the day of the Lord, because Jesus Christ IS the Lord! And there is only one Lord, for Christians.

"Grace, mercy and peace, from God our Father and Jesus Christ our
Lord." 1 Timothy 1:2
"...the commandment of God our Saviour; ...Grace, mercy and peace,
from God the Father and the Lord Jesus Christ our Saviour." Titus
1:3-4
"There is one body, and one Spirit, even as ye are called in one hope
of your calling; one Lord, one faith, one baptism, one God and Father
of all..." Ephesians 4:4-6

Yes, "the Day of the Lord in the OT was a day of judgment on the wicked" - a dreadful, dark day for the wicked. But for those who "know the terror of the Lord", that inspires them to persuade men of why Christ died, for God has given those Christians the ministry of reconciliation and they are now ambassadors for Christ. That is explained in chapter 5 below:

"For we must all appear before the judgment seat of Christ; that
everyone may receive the things done in his body, according to that
he hath done, whether good or bad. Knowing therefore the terror of the
Lord, we persuade men..." 2 Corinthians 5:10-11 K.J.V.

In 2 Thessalonians chapter 2, Christians are being warned that prior to Christ's second coming, there will be a falling away from the faith; the man of sin (the son of perdition) being revealed, that which opposes Christ and Christians. They are to stand fast during this terrible time. The book of Revelation confirms all of this. But when Christ suddenly appears, this Wicked will be revealed and destroyed at that Day of Resurrection and Judgment. Paul warned against being deceived that that Day had already started and told them what to look out for.
Yet Christians still give thanks always to God, no matter how awful things get on Earth prior to Christ's glorious return, confident of the assurances in verses 13 to 17.
The Day of the Lord was a terrible day of judgment in the OT, and it remains such when Christ the Lord suddenly comes with hosts of holy angels, to execute judgment. But Christians have nothing to fear as they have already passed over from judgment to life, in Christ, as the scriptures say:

"He that heareth my word, and believeth on him that sent me, hath
everlasting life, and shall not come into condemnation; but is passed
from death unto life." John 5:24 A.V.

Similar connection between God and Christ on the future "day of wrath and revelation of the righteous judgement of God" is stated by Paul here:

"Who will render to every man according to his deeds: to them who by
patient continuance in well doing seek for glory and honour and
immortality, eternal life: but unto them that are contentious, and do
not obey the truth, but obey unrighteousness : Indignation and wrath,
tribulation and anguish, upon every soul of man that doeth evil, of
the Jew first, and also of the Gentile; but glory, honour and peace,
to every man that worketh good, to the Jew first, and also to the
Gentile." Romans 2:6-10 A.V.

This has got nothing to do with any modern-day interpretations about "a rapture" where Christians will supposedly be whisked away so as to avoid the awfulness of the  tribulations still to unfold. This has got everything to do with knowing how the Day of Christ is the Day of the Lord's judgment. Christians look forward to how that will vindicate God and prove the righteousness of God, in Christ.
